# State definition in Viterbi Algorithm?

Tags: digital-communications, digital-filters, viterbi-algorithm

An ISI channel of length 'L+1' $\mathbf{h}=[h_0 \space h_1 \space … \space h_L]$can always be modeled as a finite state machine(FSM) of memory 'L'. For a binary input $x\in\{+1,-1\}$,a state can be defined as $\mathbf{s}=[x_{1}\space  x_{2} \space … \space x_{L}]$.

I recently came across a paper (cf. [this article](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=5257126&queryText=an+itertrack+interference+mitigation+technique+using+partial+ITI+estimation+in+pattterned+media+storage&newsearch=true&searchField=Search_All)):

Myint, L.M.M.; Supnithi, P.; Tantaswadi, P., "An Inter-Track Interference Mitigation Technique Using Partial ITI Estimation in Patterned Media Storage," Magnetics, IEEE Transactions on , vol.45, no.10, pp.3691,3694, Oct. 2009

in which $\mathbf{h}=[h_{k-1} \space h_k \space h_{k+1}]=[\beta \space b \space \beta]$, where the authors define gain=$b$ and ISI-coefficient=$\beta$ (ref:eq 3,4,5) . the noiseless channel output is defined as

\begin{equation}
y_{k} = bx_k+\beta(x_{k-1}+x_{k+1})\\
r_{k} = y_k + n_k
\end{equation}

and create a 4-state trellis using $[x_{k-1} \space x_{k+1}]$.

The branch metric is computed as $\lambda_k=(r_k-y_k)^2$.

This is approach is different from the conventional state definition $[x_{k-1} \space x_{k}]$. Since this paper is published in IEEE transactions on magnetics, I am hesitant to say that there is a mistake here but on the other hand this definition doesn't sound right to me.

I will be very grateful if someone can comment on this.

$\color{red}{New \space Edit:}$
While searching for the answer I came across another paper
(cf. [this article](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/abstractReferences.jsp?arnumber=4476459&queryText=ISI+Mitigation+Capability+of+MLSE+Direct-Detection+Receivers&newsearch=true&searchField=Search_All))

Rubsamen, M.; Gene, J.M.; Winzer, P.J.; Essiambre, R., "ISI Mitigation Capability of MLSE Direct-Detection Receivers," Photonics Technology Letters, IEEE , vol.20, no.8, pp.656,658, April15, 2008
doi: 10.1109/LPT.2008.919597

That takes a similar approach.

Comment: What doesn't sound right to you? An ISI channel of length 3 would be modeled as a finite state machine with memory length 2, which would have four states.

Comment: they are using $h_{k-1},h_{k+1}$ coefficients for defining states. wrt $h_k$, $h_{k-1}$ is past and $h_{k+1}$ is future. This is the point of confusion for me. The gain coefficient $b$ is in the middle. normally we would consider $h_k,h_{k-1}$ for state definition

Comment: I have updated my question and have included important definitions for making question more clear

Comment: It is often the case that one wants the largest entry in $\mathbf h$ to be called $h_0$ so that the peak response to input $x_k$ is at time $k$ rather than at time $k+m$. This simplifies the ISI analysis, but for ML sequence estimation using the Viterbi algorithm, it is necessary to re-adapt.

Comment: @ Dilip, I get your point but using this new definition we would be computing the likelihood of making transitions because of bit at t=k+1 but assigning the value to bit at t=k. I can't find the justification for these mismatched indices.

Comment: Also if that is the case, then MLSE would also have some parameter that would be aligned against the max(h). But since that not the case, how can we justify this shift